# Why aren't my states updating on React when using setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to make a simple to-do list on React. I do not use hooks as I haven't learned how to use them yet. The problem is the states for the fields of the to-do list aren't updating.

I put together a form with the fields I want to have on the task list and connected them to states through values. I then made a function that captures the values and updates the states through setState. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {
            taskInput,
            priorityInput,
            dateChange,
            dateInput,
            textInput,
            handleChange,
            handleClick,
            isSaveButtonDisabled 
        } = this.props
        
        return (
            <form>
                <label
                    htmlFor="task-input"
                >
                    Tarefa:
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        id="task-input"
                        name="taskInput"
                        value={ taskInput }
                        onChange={ handleChange }
                    />
                </label>
                <label
                    htmlFor="priority-input"
                >
                    Prioridade:
                    <select
                        id="priority-input"
                        name="priorityInput"
                        value={ priorityInput }
                        onChange={ handleChange }
                    >
                        <option>Baixa</option>
                        <option>Normal</option>
                        <option>Alta</option>
                        <option>Urgente</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
```

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      taskInput: '',
      priorityInput: 'Baixa',
      dateInput: '',
      textInput: '',
      isSaveButtonDisabled: true,
      savedTasks: [],
    };
  }

  handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { name, value } = target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    }, () => {
      this.setState({ isSaveButtonDisabled: this.validateFields() })
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to reactjs! I don't really have time to look into it very deeply, but here is something that could help you:
[After updating, react variables take a bit of time, until the value is actually changed. That happens async](https://blog.logrocket.com/why-react-doesnt-update-state-immediately/)

Comment: "I do not use hooks as I haven't learned how to use them yet" -- considering they are the future and there's no good reason nowadays to write class-based components, you may want to consider reading about them instead of starting with something obsolete...

Comment: And I agree with "here's no good reason nowadays to write class-based components". It's worth learning the new things, especially when you're rather new. It would be a shame if you got used to something outdated.

Comment: You're not showing how you're using the `Form` component. Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

In your onChange function you are not running the function passed. They are treated as values by react and not actual functions. I think this is because the actual implementation is from somewhere else.  You should pass it in as a return function like this:

```
<input                     
          type="text"
          id="task-input"
          name="taskInput"
          value={ taskInput }
          onChange={ () => handleChange() }        />
```

Update this on all your onChange functions that are called from the props. If it still doesnot work, try changing your handleChange function in your app component,

```
    handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { name, value } = target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    }, () => {
      this.setState({ isSaveButtonDisabled: this.validateFields() })
    });
  }
```

To :

```
    handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { name, value } = target;
    this.setState(prevState =>({
     ...prevState,
     [name]:value
    }));
   }
```

Show where you call your Form component inside the App component and ensure props where well passed to Form
Your options fields should also have a value props, which refer to the actual value passed like this :

```
      <option value = 'value'>'appeared user option'</option> 
    /* when onChange is set on the Select input field, the value passed will be  
    the value = 'value' and not 'the appeared user option' */
```

I hope I was helpful

Answer (score -1):

using functional components is the way forward and as pointed out by @ThiefMaster and @Anes

using functional components and react hook, you have

```
function App(){
 const [data, setData]=useState({
    taskInput: '',
    priorityInput: 'Baixa',
    dateInput: '',
    textInput: '',
    isSaveButtonDisabled: true,
    savedTasks: [],
 })

handleChange=(e)=>{
    setData({
        ...data,
        [e.target.id]:e.target.value
    })
}

return(
    <div>content here... NOTE: make sure yr IDs are same as variables names</div>
)
```

}

Your form will look like this

```
<input 
                    type="text"
                    id="taskInput"
                    name="taskInput"
                    value={ data.taskInput }
                    onChange={ handleChange }
                />
```

**NOTE:** Please kindly learn about functional components and react hooks as I'm also learning but this will give you insight to what you're referred to.